# QField - Incrementing SampleID failing

Tags: qgis, qfield, attribute-form

Using QField to collect field samples and have attribute forms setup.
Most are Value Map (drop-down selection) along with date and then SampleID which is incrementing;
[image]

Trying to get zero padding ie 0056 - any ideas?

Comment: One question per Question, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want zero-padding your ID field needs to be a text field (otherwise it will revert from 0056 to 56).

As for padding itself, `lpad()` is what you're looking for. Have a look in the expressions list for more details.

QGIS should be able to detect that zero-padded numbers in a text field are still numbers and `maximum()` would still get you the highest number but if that doesn't work wrap your ID field with `to_int()`.

Comment: That worked, thank you.

Comment: You're welcome! Please don't forget to mark the question as answered to help others in the future with a similar issue.